# Adding a node to the begining of a linked list results in error message I don't follow

Tags: c, linked-list

I found relevant content about this in previous posts, but I get an error message when I try to compile the suggested code. As the subject suggests, I am trying to add a node to the beginning of a linked list. I posted the entire file to provide more context...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct entry {
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};
struct entry *findEntry ( struct entry *listPtr, int match)
  {
    while ( listPtr != (struct entry *) 0)
      {
      printf ("Here is the current value%i\n", listPtr->value);
      if ( listPtr->value == match )
        return (listPtr);
      else
        listPtr = listPtr->next;
      }
    return (struct entry *) 0;
  }

void insertEntry ( struct entry *newNode, struct entry *targetPtr)
// This function inserts a node after the targe Node
{
   // set the pointer inside of new object to point to what target node is pointting to right now
   newNode->next = targetPtr->next;
   printf("Here is what is in new node value%i\n Here is what is in targetNode value %i\n",newNode->next, targetPtr->next);
   // Now move the pointer inside of target node, and point to new object
   targetPtr->next = newNode;
}
struct entry newNodef ()
  {
    struct entry node, *nodePtr;
    int newValue;
    printf("Please tell me what value you want to store in the new node\n");
    scanf("%i", &newValue);
    node.value = newValue;
    return node;
  }
void addFirst (struct entry **listStart, int value)
{
  struct entry *new_entry = ( struct entry*) malloc (sizof (struct entry));
  new_entry->value = value;
  new_entry->next =*listStart;
  *listStart = new_etnry;
}

int main (void)
{
 struct entry *findEntry ( struct entry *listPtr, int match);
 void addFirst (struct entry **listStart, int value);
 void insertEntry ( struct entry *newNode, struct entry *targetPtr);
 struct entry newNodef ();
 struct entry n1, n2, n3;
 struct entry *listPtr, *targetPtr, *listStart = &n1;
 int search;

 n1.value = 100;
 n1.next = &n2;

 n2.value = 200;
 n2.next = &n3;

 n3.value =300;
 n3.next = (struct entry *) 0;
 struct entry tempNode = newNodef();
 listPtr = &tempNode;
 targetPtr = &n2;
 insertEntry ( listPtr, targetPtr);
 printf("Here is what the new node is pointing to now %i. \n", tempNode.next->value );
 printf ("Enter value to locate: ");
 scanf ("%i", &search);
 listPtr = findEntry (listStart, search);

 if ( listPtr != (struct entry *) 0)
   printf ("Found %i.\n", listPtr->value);
 else
   printf ("Not found. \n");
 int v=700;
 addFirst(&listStart, v);
 return 0;
```

}

Here are the error messages...

```
$ make
gcc  temp.c -o temp
temp.c: In function 'addFirst':
temp.c:42:61: error: expected expression before 'struct'
   struct entry *new_entry = ( struct entry*) malloc (sizof (struct entry));
                                                             ^
temp.c:45:16: error: 'new_etnry' undeclared (first use in this function)
   *listStart = new_etnry;
                ^
temp.c:45:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make: *** [temp] Error 1
```

I basically followed the advice provided at the bottom of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674616/c-adding-node-to-head-of-linked-list) post since I could understand his explanation. If there is a better way of doing this w/o using pointer to a pointer, please let advise.

Comment: sizof should be sizeof？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Spelling mistake in `sizof` -->  `sizeof`
2. Spelling mistake in `new_etnry` --> `new_entry`
3. In `insertentry` change the printf specifier to %p or change the arguments to `newNode->value` and `targetPtr->value`
4. Unused variable `nodePtr` in `newNodef`

Comment: 3: From the text, it seems that the format specifier should be `%i`, but the arguments should take `->value` instead of `->next`.